# Unable to type letter 't' inside WebStorm terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am facing a very weird issue with WebStorm. I am unable to enter letter `t` inside the terminal within WebStorm. There is no issue if I type within the code editor or elsewhere. But I have no clue why this is happening?

Not sure if anything is related to tab because when it has some predefined words for git or other things it give suggestions. But when I am trying to create new file or name with `t`, nothing is happening.

Checked even the settings, but not sure what is happening as I am new to this IDE.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Maybe you wanted [superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: 1) If you go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- there is a button next to the local search field. It allows to locate IDE actions associated with the shortcuts. Click on it and press `t` in the appeared popup -- what actions will it locate for you? Show a screenshot. 2) Do you use IdeaVim plugin perhaps? 3) If all good, will the issue persist after you disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart the IDE?

Comment: If the problem remains after applying the proposed steps above please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and attach the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) for further investigation